# How can I integrate Dialogflow CX on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I use a package called dialogflow_flutter, but it only works with Dialogflow ES.

I know there are other packages like dialogflow_grpc, but they are not currently compatible with Flutter 3.

I want to know how to connect my flutter project with Dialogflow CX, and how can I configure it.